# How to return JSON including the html text of the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to return error html text with "IsError" flag.
How could I implement it?
Here is my trial.
Assuming that I submitted the Ajax.BeginForm and error occured on server side.

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    var number = GetErrorNumber();
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect("/Error?number=" + number, false);
}
```

**View Error/index**

```
<div>
An error occurred<br>
Error number : @ViewBag.ErrorNumber
</div>
```

**ErrorController** I want to return JSON including view html and "IsError = true"!!

```
ViewBag.ErrorNumber = number;
return View();
```

Client side JavaScript catches the returned value.
And the returned html text would renders if "IsError" was true.(I wish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should return json and create the HTML DIV on client side using javascript. I think you can not return HTML in json.

Comment: Why create content with javascript if your already creating html in the same response?

Comment: I am suggesting to always return Json result in case of error instead of a view.

Comment: @Jonas Stensved I could return json or html either on the ErrorController I guess.

Comment: Thanks @Asif. Your suggestion seems the best I can do.

Comment: My point was simply not to use javascript to modify the html DOM when you can achieve the same result within the original plain html output.

Answer (score 0):

Your need seems unusal wich is often an indication of a problem elsewhere.

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Catch the error in the action with a standard try-catch.
2. Check if it is an ajax request with [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx) and return json if true, otherwise return a standard html view

Here's an example on your action:

```
    public ActionResult FormPostHandler()
    {

        try
        {

            // Process request

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    Success = false,
                    ErrorNo = 1
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return View("ErrorView"); // add model for error
            }
        }


    }
```

**UPDATE:**

After reading your question again I might have figured out what you're trying to achieve.

1. Use the above code to output a json result.
2. On the client-side, create the html needed to show your error if `Success` is false and add it to your HTML DOM.

I would say it's bad practice to return html with JSON, it's better to let JSON just carry information and let your presentation layer (html & javascript) handle the appearance.

If you're using jQuery, prototype etc this should be quite straightforward.